# Share parts of git repository to group of users like in SVN

Tags: git, svn

Imagine file system stored in svn:

```
 - a
  - a1
  - a2
  - a3
     - **a3file1**
     - **a3file2**
 - b
 - c
 - d
 - .git
```

Under this file system is defined git repository.

What I wanna do is to set rights to our two groups and three external programmers like this.

- first group "admins" will have rights on all repository.
- second group "designers" will have rights on folders a (with subdirectories) and `b`.

And:

- first programmer will have rights on folder `a` only
- second on folder `a` exclude files `a3file1` and `a3file2`.
- and the third one will have rights only for folder `d`.

**Important**:

I agree that some sort of solution could be definition of subrepositories or individual repositories for every folder separately.
But imagine that my real file system is much more complicated to share rights to folders.

Comment: I've never seen git permissions down to the file level in git, and I think it's probably a bad idea and hope it isn't too tragic if something goes wrong, as it definitly will. That said, you could probably set something up by checking permissions in git hooks. Alternatively, and better: create individual branches for each user/group and manage permissions at the branch level.

Comment: yeah i was worried about that. But as it is said hope dies last. I still hope that someone will find solution to make it like in svn. In SVN it is possible to define inside of branch for which file or folders have rights some groups or users. But thanks for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set that kind of fine-grained *write* level access if your repos are managed (as an [authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#auth)) by **[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html)**.

See "[access rules](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#rules)": with [VREF syntax](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#vref-makers-shipped-with-gitolite), you can limit push to files or folders within a git repo.

> Here's an example. Say you don't want junior developers pushing changes to the Makefile, because it's quite complex:
>
> ```
> repo foo
>         RW+                             =   @senior_devs
>         RW                              =   @junior_devs
>
>         -   VREF/NAME/Makefile          =   @junior_devs
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply i will check this solution out.

Comment: Hi i tried out your solution, but problem is, that its work only for pull and push requests. What i need is. That users will be able to clone and see only files or folders with given rights. Is something like this even possible?

Comment: @pesoklp13 not possible within the same repo (if you access a part of a repo, you access it all). If you are using submodules, then yes, you can deny clone for some submodules.

Comment: Thanks for answer so thats means there is any easy way to migrate rights from svn repository into Git without define another repos or submodules. thx.